# If $\alpha\to\beta$ is a tautology, then $\beta$ or $\lnot\alpha$ are tautologies.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

> Let $\alpha, \beta $ be some propositions, such that $\alpha\to\beta$ is a tautology. Let $A$ be the set of variables in $\alpha$ and $B$ be the set of variables in $\beta$. Prove  that if $A\cap B=\varnothing$, then $\beta$ is a tautology or $\lnot\alpha $ is a tautology.

I've tried solving it but in my solution I didn't use the fact that the intersection is empty so I want to find out what I did wrong..

Here is my attempt:

Assume towards contradiction there exists an assignment $v$, such that $v(\lnot\alpha)=F$ and $v(\beta)=F$.
Then as $\alpha\to\beta $ is a tautology, $v(\alpha\to\beta)=T$. As $v(\lnot\alpha)=F$, then $v(\alpha)=T$ and $v(\beta)$ must be true, which is a contradiction since we assumed $v(\beta)=F$.

Comment: I think it's about time you should use $\rm\LaTeX$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it. :)

Comment: No. Consider $p \rightarrow p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect, as you did not rule out a possible case in which $v(\neg \alpha) = F$ and $u(\beta) = F$ for different $v, u$. To prove this properly, you must suppose there are some assignments $v, u$ in which $v(\neg \alpha) = F$ and $u(\beta) = F$ without assuming that $v = u$.

More precisely, the proof begins like this:

Suppose that neither $\neg \alpha$ nor $\beta$ are tautologies. The fact that $\neg \alpha$ is not a tautology means that there is some $v$ such that $v(\neg \alpha) = F$. Similarly, the fact that $\beta$ is not a tautology means that there is some $u$ such that $u(\beta) = F$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! I don't understand why I need to consider two different assignments.. do you mean that there might exists a sort of piecewise assignment that connects v and u?

Comment: @MathCurious See the revised answer.

Comment: Great thank you very much! So just to be clear, if neither are tautologies, it doesn't neccesarily mean that there exist a single assignment v that assigns both  ¬α  and β to false, if the condition of the empty intersection is not there? and because it's there, we can make an assignment v' such that v'(x)=v(x) if x is in ¬α and u(x) if x is in β?

Comment: @MathCurious This is correct. Consider the very simple case of $\alpha = P$, $\beta = P$. Then neither $\neg \alpha$ nor $\beta$ is a tautology, and $\alpha \implies \beta$. But there is no variable assignment $v$ such that $v(\neg \alpha) = F$ and $v(\beta) = F$. However, in this specific case, we can take the two variable assignments $v$ and $u$ and combine them into a variable assignment $v'$ such that $v'(\neg \alpha) = F$ and $v'(\beta) = F$ in the manner that you stated.